# Independence Among Dataset Observations

Tags: statistics, independence

The Machine Learning algorithm I would like to implement assumes that observations are obtained independently. What test could I perform in order to validate this assumption? Would that be a requirement as part of data exploration?

Comment: You might consider posting this to http://stats.stackexchange.com as well, if it is not well-received here.